# Will Titanium 1.7.2 work properly on XCode 4.0.2?

Tags: iphone

The Titanium module works great with Titanium 1.5.1 and XCode 3, but the module does not properly work with Titanium 1.7.1 and XCode 4.0.2.  I got the following error:

> Error: Traceback (most recent call last):File "/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/1.7.0/iphone/builder.py", line 1139, in main execute_xcode("iphonesimulator%s" % link_version,["GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS=**LOG__ID**=%s DEPLOYTYPE=development TI_DEVELOPMENT=1 DEBUG=1 TI_VERSION=%s %s" % (log_id,sdk_version,debugstr)],False)File "/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/1.7.0/iphone/builder.py", line 1057, in execute_xcode output = run.run(args,False,False,o)File "/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/1.7.0/iphone/run.py" line 39, in ru sys.exit(rc)

Why is this type of error occurring?

Answer (score 0):

I would first start by building and running the module Xcode project generated by Titanium CLI. This will allow for you to easily toggle things like the Titanium SDK version for quick comparisons and interactive debugging, as opposed to the more disconnected approach using Titanium Developer.